# high resolution snapshot in opengl with framebuffer

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, glreadpixels

i am using opengl to set texture to 3d object.then snapshot and blend it other picture.
i wanna to high resolution snapshot(3000*1500 px). is it possible in opengl?
my code is:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

DrawScene();
DrawText();

glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);

if (g_fboSamples > 0)
{
// Multisample rendering so copy the pixel data in the multisample
// color render buffer image to the FBO containing the offscreen
// texture image.

    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, g_fbo);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, g_fboResolveTarget);
    glBlitFramebufferEXT(0, 0, g_fboWidth, g_fboHeight,
        0, 0, g_fboWidth, g_fboHeight,
    GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
}

// At this point we now have our scene fully rendered to our offscreen
// texture 'g_offscreenTexture'. This is where you would perform any
// post processing to the offscreen texture.

// Finally to display the offscreen texture to the screen we draw a screen
// aligned full screen quad and attach the offscreen texture to it.

BYTE* pixels = new BYTE[ 3 *g_fboWidth*g_fboHeight];
//glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);



glReadPixels(0, 0, g_fboWidth, g_fboHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
bitmap.create(g_fboWidth, g_fboHeight);
bitmap.setPixels(pixels,g_fboWidth, g_fboHeight,3);
bitmap.flipVertical();
bitmap.saveBitmap("test.png");
glViewport(0, 0, g_windowWidth, g_windowHeight);   
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
DrawFullScreenQuad();
//g_fboWidth= 2732, g_fboHeight=1536 , g_windowWidth=683 and g_windowHeight=384
```

test.png:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaYe4.jpg

Comment: "Is it possible with GL?" Yes. But what is really the question?

Comment: yes! i wanna to have high resolution snapshot.

Comment: You can only get a screenshot in a high resolution if you have your stuff rendered in that high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your viewport in the framebuffer is to small. Call glViewport(g_fboWidth, g_fboHeight).

Comment: i call "glViewport(0, 0, g_fboWidth, g_fboHeight);" with g_fboWidth= 2732, g_fboHeight=1536 but in test.png only window size screen shoted!!

Comment: do you call it after you bind your framebuffer?